# Lithium Ion Battery Remaining Life Cycle Prediction

Tags: temperature, electric-current, batteries

What are the parameters required for remaining useful life predictions? For example, battery temperature and battery capacity values are helpful for remaining useful life cycle prediction. Other than these, what parameters will be best suited for predicting remaining useful life cycles?